# select all zip codes within radius very slow when using IN operator

Tags: sql, google-maps

I have a table with all of the zip codes in the US and my query is selecting the zip code boundary coordinates and an apart count for each zip code. Now if I specify a certain zip code this operation is pretty fast. The problem is when I add the IN operator so I can get all of the zip codes within a certain radius. I used the Great Circle Function shown here http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360 to do this. The problem I think now is the whole operation is running for every zip code returned from the great circle function. The end result is for a google map but that is irrelevant for improving the sql query. How should this query be modified to improve performance? I am already indexing zipcodes. Any help would be appreciated!

```
select s.ZipCode, count(a.[Apartment_Complex]) apartCount, b.Longitude, b.Latitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability s  
                left join pdx_apart_view a on s.ZipCode = left([Zip Code], 5)  
                left join ZipCodeBoundaries b on s.ZipCode = b.ZipCode 
                Where Ordering % 10 = 0 and s.zipcode in 
                                      (Select zipcode from ZipCodeServiceAvailability 
                                       Where AzumaWebInput.dbo.F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE
                                             ((Select Latitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --latitude
                                              (Select Longitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --longitude
                                              Latitude,
                                              Longitude) <  200) -- get all zips within 200 miles of 78745
                Group By s.ZipCode, IsServiced, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Ordering  
                Order by s.ZipCode, b.Ordering
```

Comment: How long does the subquery take and how many records does it return?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @DanBracuk 15 seconds and 187 thousand records

Comment: @GordonLinoff ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/ZCTA5/tl_2012_us_zcta510.zip

Comment: @osiris355 . . . That is the data itself.  What database engine are you using?  Your code suggests SQL Server.  Which version?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 but all of this will be a ado.net string in c# when finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are calculating the great circle distance on every record in your table.

A faster query would be to get all the zip codes in a rectangle between two latitudes and two longitudes.

Make sure there is an index on the ZipCodeServiceAvailability table with both the latitude and longitude field.

EDIT:

Replace

```
(Select zipcode from ZipCodeServiceAvailability 
                                   Where AzumaWebInput.dbo.F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE
                                         ((Select Latitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --latitude
                                          (Select Longitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --longitude
                                          Latitude,
                                          Longitude) <  200)
```

with

```
(Select zipcode from ZipCodeServiceAvailability
 Where Latitude between @Latitude - 100 and @Latitude + 100
   and Longitude between @Longitude - 100 and @Longitude + 100)
```

Comment: I tried with a couple coordinates and it took 3 min and returned 5 mil records  Where Latitude between 30.2077 - 100 and 30.29838 + 100
         and Longitude between -97.8182 - 100 and -97.74735 + 100)

Comment: Were all the records returned in the correct range?  (That is, can you find some that aren't?)  If not, can you figure out why they are being returned?

Comment: I got it.  Instead of 100, which was half of 200 miles, you need the amount in difference in longitude and difference in latitude.

Comment: @ Marlin Pierce. I apologize but I am not sure I follow

Comment: Replace 100 with the distance as a difference in latitude or longitude.  So maybe it should be 5 degrees.  Try 5 and see that the result are fewer.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is how can I tell this how many miles to go out and also how can I use this with my other query to limit the amount of rows it searches

Comment: Is this correct? Where Ordering % 10 = 0 and s.zipcode in 
         (Select zipcode from ZipCodeServiceAvailability Where AzumaWebInput.dbo.F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE((Select Latitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), 
                    (Select Longitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), 
                    s.Latitude,
                    s.Longitude) <  200 and (Latitude between 30.2077 - 4 and 30.2077 + 4 and Longitude between -97.8182 - 4 and -97.8182 + 4))

Comment: The database optimizer can index at least one of latitude or longitude and use the index to very quickly limit the results to the rectangle described.  Even if it can only index one, the comparison of the other between two bounds will be faster than the great circle calculation.  As a bonus, if you do between longitudes and between latitudes and great circle calculation, the database optimizer will do the indexes first, and only do the great circle calculation within the rectangle.

Comment: Converting between miles or meters and lat/long is something you may have to surf the internet for more information on.  Latitude is a straight up conversion, but Longitude takes some understanding as it changes as a function of Latitude.  For your purposes, you could use the Latitude conversion for both since you only need to limit your results which you will have to post-process with the great circle distance calculation.

Comment: After using the 69 miles per 1 degree formula, this code works great! (1 Degree divided by 69 Miles = 0.0144927536231884. Take that number times each mile you are searching and you can use that in an IF statement to create a variable for each. Example: IF distance = 50 { $miles = 0.7246376811594203; } etc... That's how I was able to use your script and replaced the 100 and $miles variable. So thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right.  But why are you using a subquery at all?  The subquery is saying "is the zip code in the original table in the list of zip codes that are within 200 (miles?) of another location?".

This is the same as asking:  "Is this zip code within 200 (miles?) of the location?"

And you would phrase that as:

```
select s.ZipCode, count(a.[Apartment_Complex]) apartCount, b.Longitude, b.Latitude
from ZipCodeServiceAvailability s left join
     pdx_apart_view a
     on s.ZipCode = left([Zip Code], 5) left join
     ZipCodeBoundaries b
     on s.ZipCode = b.ZipCode 
Where Ordering % 10 = 0 and
      AzumaWebInput.dbo.F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE((Select Latitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --latitude
                                                (Select Longitude from ZipCodeServiceAvailability where ZipCode = '78745'), --longitude
                                                Latitude,
                                                Longitude
                                               ) <  200)
Group By s.ZipCode, IsServiced, b.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Ordering  
Order by s.ZipCode, b.Ordering
```

Comment: This is even slower. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @osiris355 . . . Wow!  I'm really surprised.  I could sort of imagine how it might take the same time, but not slower.  Have you compared the execution plans?  Are they the same?  If so, then the original query is not executing the subquery for every row in the outer query.

Comment: With your changes it ran for 5 minutes without completion so I stopped it